# Is there any alternate way without using ajax for partial post-back in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

For example:
If I enable partial post-back only for a part of my code, in case of pressing a button in asp.net.
How can I implement it in alternate way without using "ajax"? or if it's possible or not? 
Thank you

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnOpen" runat="server" Text="Open" AccessKey="O" OnClick="btnOpen_Click" />
```

Comment: i *think* 'partial post-back' = 'ajax'. i.e., they are different terms for the same thing, so doing a partial post-back means 'ajax', not doing it means 'no ajax'. maybe something like 'Signal R'? (not sure about that.)

Comment: thank you for response !